# Clustering of colors in a thermal image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, cluster-analysis

I am working on detection of dental issues using thermography. I need to separate the all the given colours in the image  into separate clusters (4-7 in number) so that the high-temperature zones (seen white in the image) are seen separately, which can be followed by thresholding if need be.

I am also attaching a sample of the images I will be working on. I am looking for a suitable program to carry out the execution in MATLAB.

I've already worked on the same, the program being attached in the previous question, which gives 3 clusters only.Since I'm a beginner, I need help in establishing more clusters.

image obtained using thermal camera on which clustering is to be carried out [image] 
the closest I could get to the sort of clustering I want to carry out. here, in this image  green-blue cluster and white cluster are in the same image, which i want to have in separate clusters, hence the need of more clusters[image]
expected result after clustering and thresholding[image]

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com//help/how-to-ask). Your question is too broad for SO, shows no attempt, and seems to be asking for recommendations for software. All of these are reasons to mark the question as out-of-scope. I recommend you edit your question and clarify what you need, and show what you have done so far (you do show image results, but code is more relevant here).

Comment: How is this question different from your previous two questions?

Comment: NO REASON TO SCREAM IN YOUR UPPERCASE HEADLINES. Thank you.

Comment: this question is board!

Comment: @Anony-Mousse , sure , thank you, will be careful next time.

Comment: @beaker I've tried to edit the question, I actually have earlier used a program for three clusters. I need more than three clusters, actually.  I'm not familiar with coding as such, that's why I need help.

Comment: Then why not add the code that you used for 3 clusters and your attempts to modify it? Why make us guess at what you've already attempted? Do you have access to an intensity image instead of the false-color image you you included in your question?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I tried to edit the question, actually, haven't used the forum a lot, my bad. As for the attempt, I've already posted the program in the previous and the only question that i have asked, I can post it here also if required. For the software, my work has to be in MATLAB. Please go through the question, I hope it is proper now.

Comment: @Mohammadnagdawi I've tried to elucidate now.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than hoping that by chance clustering does what you need, I'd rather just use the ground truth you have...

In case you haven't noticed: **there is a color index to the right**. That is an easy to use, *ordered* (this is extremely beneficial over clustering, in particular to set thresholds) easy to detect key to interpreting these images without hoping on a random generator.

Note that you will likely also need to read off the numbers that give the color scale, in order to compare images.

Answer (score 0):

You can read your image file in Matlab and then convert the data from `RGB` format to `HSL` or `HSV` with the function `rgb2hsl()` or `rgb2hsv()`.

They are two alternative representations of the RGB color model. Then you can easily make your discrimination with the value of `H` which is abbreviated for **hue**.

For more information take a look at the following link: [HLS and HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)